# How to actually "clear" a vector in C++?

Tags: c++, vector

How to clear content in a simple way?

If I use `vec_vec.clear();` only, there is still something in the vector that has not been cleaned up.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec_vec(10);
    vec_vec[0].push_back(1);
    vec_vec[0].push_back(2);
    vec_vec[0].push_back(3);
    vec_vec[0].push_back(4);

    for (auto i : vec_vec[0])
        std::cout << i << " ";
    std::cout << "." << std::endl;

    vec_vec.clear();
    for (auto i : vec_vec[0])
        std::cout << i << " ";
    std::cout << "." << std::endl;


    vec_vec[0].clear();
    for (auto i : vec_vec[0])
        std::cout << i << " ";
    std::cout << "." << std::endl;

    for (int i=0; i<vec_vec.size(); i++)
        vec_vec.erase(vec_vec.begin() + i);
    for (auto i : vec_vec[0])
        std::cout << i << " ";
    std::cout << "." << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

```
1 2 3 4 *
0 0 3 4 *
*
*
```

Comment: Have you tried std::vector's erase function?

Comment: Attempting to access a vector out of bounds causes undefined behavior. You do that after `.clear()`ing it.

Comment: @DylanFouche There's nothing wrong with `clear`. It does what the OP wants.

Comment: Your code invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) and is thus simply broken and *any* result is ok. Once you break the language rules and do something you are not allowed to do, you leave the realm of well defined behaviour. The compiler is not required to prevent you from breaking the rules, it can just generate garbage if you do. It is entirely on *you* to know *all* the rules and follow them at all times - which you didn't here.

Comment: That code didn’t produce the output listed in the question. The code doesn’t write any *s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> vec_vec.clear();
> for (auto i : vec_vec[0])
> ```

After this `clear`, `vec_vec` is empty, so the expression `vec_vec[0]` has undefined behavior.

Undefined behavior means *anything at all* might happen, and it's the fault of the program, not the fault of the C++ compiler, library, etc. So it might act like an empty vector, it might crash your program, it might print some values, or it might do what you expect today, then break at the worst possible time later on.

See also [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior) on Undefined, unspecified, and implementation-defined behavior.